Reach a raspberri pi from a docker container
I have an Ubuntu host with two ethernet interfaces, one connected to the internet, the other connected to a Raspberri Pi.
Goal: reach the Raspberri Pi from my container (ping 169.254.1.25). I can not use Docker's host network because it conflicts with other requirements I have.
These are the relevant IPs I am testing:

192.168.178.1 my router in the WLAN
192.168.178.155 my host in my WLAN
169.254.1.25 my Raspberri Pi connected to an ethernet interface in the linux host
169.254.1.100: the second eth interface in my host (the one connected to the Raspberri pi)
8.8.8.8: a known internet host
172.70.0.1: docker0 on the host (bridge created by docker)
172.70.0.2: veth on the container (created by docker)

The Ubuntu host can ping everything:

my router (192.168.178.1)
itself (both 169.254.1.100 and 192.168.178.155)
the Raspberri Pi (169.254.1.25)
the 8.8.8.8

My docker container, started in the default manner (Docker attaches the docker0 bridge), gets the following interfaces:

eth0: 172.70.0.2
lo: 127.0.0.1

The container can ping:

itself (127.0.0.1 and 172.70.0.2)
my router (192.168.178.1)
the docker0 bridge (172.70.0.1)
the host as seen on WLAN (192.168.178.155)
the host on the second eth interface (169.254.1.100)
the 8.8.8.8

But it has trouble with:

the Raspberri Pi (169.254.1.25)

This is the routing table in the host:
» ip route
default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.1.0/24 dev enx000ec6a42183 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.1.100 metric 100 
172.70.0.0/24 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.70.0.1 
192.168.178.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.155 metric 600 

IP forwarding is enabled on the host:
» sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

These are the docker networks:
» docker network ls 
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
8e2d62a7186d   bridge    bridge    local
4d041aedcd2a   host      host      local
71278e64d14b   none      null      local

The routing table in the docker container:
root@8f50776e53dc:~# ip route
default via 172.70.0.1 dev eth0 
172.70.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.70.0.2 

The host routing table clearly specifies what to do when it sees a packet with destination 169.254.1.x: send it on the interface connected to Raspberri Pi.
Why is it not working then? Routing is enabled!

Probably because more than just docker mess with the iptables or nftables on the host. Consider adding the output of iptables-save and nft list ruleset to your post.

Welcome, Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.
